# 2D or 3D simplex/Perlin noise?

Tags: java, 3d, 2d, noise, procedural-generation

I am working on a project that procedurally generates a navigable "planet" that can be seen from far away (i.e: without any visible "terrain"/height difference. This would simply show water and land) or close up (exploring the planet from a person's view as opposed to a "spacecraft's" view i.e: actually seeing the height difference in hills and valleys). For this I was wondering if I should use 2D or 3D noise as I've seen both on various sites. I was also wondering whether I should use simplex or Perlin noise. I know the uses but will the loading time difference be that severe or should I just stick with Perlin noise? Thanks in advance. Also, less importantly, how would I go about implementing the output into JavaFX?

Comment: Just to make your choice even harder, there's also Fractal Brownian Motion - check out this [tutorial](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131507/a_realtime_procedural_universe_.php?page=2) on Gamasutra for making procedural planets. The author uses 3D noise there, and gives some pros and cons of 2D vs 3D.

Comment: It says that it uses Perlin noise. I assume this means Perlin noise is the way to go?

Comment: Yes, to follow the tutorial you would use Perlin. This is not the only way to go, but it is a start. Once you get it working, you can switch it to another noise function and see what you think of it.

Comment: He uses OpenGL as the rendering software. Would you recommend this and how do I get it installed (I can't find anything)?

Comment: OpenGL is normally already installed on your computer. To use it with Java, try [LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org/).

Comment: As for output, that depends a lot on what you want; "exploring the planet" is pretty vague.  Is this meant to be a real time FPS game?  Click & point education simulation?

Comment: @Pikalek It should be a first person exploration type of game such as this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rt6SYThgV24

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition, a 2D generator gives a value for every X,Y coordinate input, whereas a 3D generator does the same for every X,Y,Z coordinate.  If you're only interested in generating a height map to wrap around the sphere, use 2D.  If you need something that generates values for the interior (caves, mineral composition, etc) then use 3D.

This SO entry on [Simplex versus Perlin noise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439350/simplex-noise-vs-perlin-noise) covers a number of pros & cons of each.